# Change color of a button every second

Tags: java, android

I want to bulid a reaction game where you have to click on a colour changing button when it's the right color (red). How can i display a color and change it after a second to another random color till the right colour appears.

````
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_farberkennung);

        b_zurück = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_zurück);
        b_start3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_start3);
        b_randomColor = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_randomcolor);

        final int background;
        final Random rand = new Random();
        final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        list.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        list.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow));
        //list.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        //list.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        //list.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.olive));
        //list.add(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
        background = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));

        b_start3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                b_start3.setEnabled(false);
                b_randomColor.setBackgroundColor(background);

//loop random colours till red appears

                while (background != getResources().getColor(R.color.red)) {
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            b_randomColor.setBackgroundColor(background);
                        }

                    }, 1000);
                }

                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        });

        b_randomColor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (background == (getResources().getColor(R.color.red))) {
                    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    currentTime = endTime - startTime;
                    b_randomColor.setText(currentTime + " MS");
                    b_randomColor.setEnabled(false);
                    b_start3.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by this way : 
create a new java class file called **Timer**

```
public class Timer {

  private thread t ;
  public boolean runTimer ;
  public long delay ;
  public int msg = 0;
  private Handler handler ;

  public Timer(Handler handler , long delay , int msg){
      this.handler = handler ;
      runTimer = true ;
      this.delay = delay ;
      this.msg = msg ;
      t = new thread();
      t.start();
  }

  public class thread extends Thread {

      @Override
      public void run(){
          while (runTimer){
              try{
                  thread.sleep(delay);
              }catch (Exception e){}

              Message message = handler.obtainMessage(msg);
              handler.sendMessage(message);
          }
      }
  }

  public void playTimer (boolean play){
      runTimer = play ;
  }

}
```

then add this message handler inside your activity and inside that handler you can test your background color if it is red

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    .........
}
// here the code you add to your activity
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (background != getResources().getColor(R.color.red)){
           b_randomColor.setBackgroundColor(background);
        }else {
           // you could stop your timer thread like that ...
           // timer.playTimer(false);
        }
    }
};
```

and finally start your timer inside your like that :

```
 final Timer timer;
 timer = new Timer(handler , 1000 , "time");
```