# Android ImageView Color infinite loop

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I want to create an icon which switches between 2 colours after every sec in an infinite loop programatically.

I can create a recursive function but that will block my main thread, I am thinking of creating a custom view and using post delayed to change colors and easier solution

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56486075/change-color-of-a-button-every-second) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of solutions using coroutine Flows, which I think is a little simpler than using `postDelayed` (at least if you're familiar with coroutines).

First a helper function:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.repeatForever(): Flow<T> = flow {
    while(true) { emitAll(this@repeatForever) }
}
```

#### Traditional views

```
// in Activity.onCreate() or Fragment.onViewCreated():
flowOf(Color.RED, Color.BLUE)
    .onEach { color ->
        ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(
            binding.button,
            ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
        )
        delay(1000)
    }
    .repeatForever()
    .launchIn(lifecycleScope) // in a fragment use viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope
```

#### Compose

```
private val buttonColor by remember {
    flowOf(Color.Red, Color.Blue)
        .onEach { delay(1000) }
        .repeatForever()
        .collectAsState(Color.Blue)
}

Button(
    //...
    color = buttonColor
) //...
```